# Simple VBA Select Case statement not working, Why not?

Tags: vba, switch-statement, case

Simple Select Case statement is not working as expected. Message should show this as falling into the "too long" bucket but it comes up as "too short"

```
Lenn = 20
    Select Case Lenn
    Case 7
        msg = "You've entered " & Lenn & " digits, this is ok"
    Case 11
        msg = "You've entered " & Lenn & " digits, is ok"
    Case 12
        msg = "You've entered " & Lenn & " digits, this is ok"
    Case 13
        msg = "You've entered " & Lenn & " digits, this is ok"
    Case 17
        msg = "You've entered " & Lenn & " digits, this is ok"
    Case Is < 7
        msg = "Hmm…. The number you entered is too short. Can you try again?"
    Case Is > 17
        msg = "Hmm…. The number you entered is too long. Can you try again?"
    Case Is = 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16
        msg = "Hmm…. The number you entered is not the right length. Can you try again?"
    Case Else
        msg = "Hmm…. The number you entered is not the right length. Can you try again?"
    End Select
```

Comment: This worked for me. When you hover over Lenn at the Select Case, does it say 20? Is Lenn declared somewhere else and, if so, what type is it?

Comment: Lenn = Len(CStr(clean_string)) is how I am getting Lenn

Comment: Do you ever declare the type of Lenn or do you just set it? I would suggest declaring it as I show in my answer below so you always know what the type of the variable will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will enter the "too short" portion of your case statement if Lenn is a string. Try forcing it to be an integer before assigning it by adding this to the top of your code:

```
Dim Lenn As Integer
```

Comment: That was it dammit. * smacks my head* I feel like a tool. I tried converting it using cInt before I asked this question here and it didn't work. I had it DIM as a string. Anyway, thank you!!

Comment: No problem. Considering the Len function returns and int, I would have expected your code to work. I often will use "Option Explicit" which forces you to declare your variable types. Just type "Option Explicit" at the top of your vba file below the "Option Compare Database".